# `const int <variable>` cannot appear in a constant-expression

Tags: c++, static, constants

I have the following declarations:

```
class Rm
{
public:
    //defined message types
    static const int HELLO;
}
```

*in the cpp file I have:*

`const int Rm::HELLO = 1;`

But when I try to use this in a method from another class:

```
int
Rn::ProcessMessages()
{
    messagesIter iter = messages.begin();
    while(iter != messages.end())
    {
        switch(iter->first)
        {
            case Rm::HELLO:
                myID = iter->second;
                break;  
        }
    }
}
```

I get this:
*error: ‘Rm::HELLO’ cannot appear in a constant-expression case Rm::HELLO:*

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: static const int HELLO =1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to use the `HELLO` value in a `switch`, it needs to be known by the compiler at this point. Which essentially, for a member constant of integral type, means providing the initializer value in the declaration. Thus, instead of

```
static const int HELLO;
```

do

```
static const int HELLO = -1;
```

In spite of the initializer this is still just a **pure declaration**. A separate **definition** is needed if you take the address of this. Just don't take the address.

---

The above works for integral types, but even a `double` member constant can't be defined in this way, for unknown reasons. One alternative then is to use C++11 `constexpr`, but at this point in time that limits the portability of the code. C++03 alternatives for constants of non-integral types include

- Use a namespace level constant, not a member.
- Use a function that produces (a reference to) the value.
- Define the constant in a class template, derive your class from a specialization.

---

As a final note, in C++ do reserve all uppercase names such as `HELLO` for **macros**. That way you reduce undesired name collisions and text substitutions, and the code gets easier on the eye too. I.e., in C++ use the name `hello`, or `Hello`, or...

All uppercase is used in some languages, notably Java and Python, as a convention for names of constants, mainly because in original C constants had to be expressed as macros.

In these languages all uppercase has no ill effect other than being an eyesore, but C++ does have a preprocessor.

Answer (score 4):

The member variable is a constant, but it's not a *compile time* constant. For that you need the `constexpr` keyword that was introduced in C++11:

```
class Rm
{
public:
    //defined message types
    static constexpr int HELLO = 1;
};
```

If you don't have a C++11 capable compiler, you can use enumerations instead:

```
class Rm
{
public:
    //defined message types
    enum
    {
        HELLO = 1
    };
};
```

Comment: I fixed the "have to" about enumerations (wrong, there are other ways), but fixing the point about `constexpr` would require more extensive editing. Just be aware that "you need constexpr" is also wrong, for the case at hand. An ordinary "static const" with initializer is for basic type, as long as the address is not explicitly or implicitly taken (in which case a definition is needed).